# Does xbox live gold membership stack when I purchase a new one?

Tags: xbox-network

I currently have an Xbox Live Gold membership that will expire in March 2011. However the price of membership is increasing to $59.99 starting November 1, 2010.

If I buy a 12 month membership now at the current price of $49.99, will the additional 12 months be added on to my existing membership or will I start a new membership which will expire 12 months after I buy it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, they do. You can lock the lower price so when it auto-renews you save $20.

See [here](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/pricelock/default.htm)

> One year subscription at $39.99 for the first year with auto-renewal at the then current annual price following year one

Comment: +1 Simple, direct, links to credible source, and even provides the extra information he wants to know.  I cannot think of a better answer.

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work any longer :(

Answer (score 5):

Yes, additional purchased membership time will stack. In addition to the one-year lock-in price currently offered by Microsoft, you can buy scratch cards at pretty much any retailer where games are sold. These can be bought at the current subscription price, and redeemed either now (and stacked with existing time) or sold to your friends later for a teeny tiny profit.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: **Yes, it is stacked to my knowledge.**
You can view this in the "Account section" of your home screen dashboard under "Settings", "Account".
Also, if you want to remove the "Auto renewal" and remove the Credit card from the account you will have to call Microsoft and they may take 3-7 days. There may be an option somewhere in the accounts.microsoft section of your live account although if the card is associated with the membership, it will not be able to be removed without the gold membership being removed...

Comment: That's good, but you don't actually answer the question.

Comment: Yes, they do stack, you can check this in the "Accounts" section of your dash, apologies, I figured it was answered.

Comment: That's the point of answers.  Additional info is great, but you still need to answer the question.